# MySQL - Interpret NULL as 0

Tags: mysql

i have the following MySQL-Query:

```
$sql = "SELECT `eid` FROM `"._ST_EVENT."` WHERE `tid` = ".$tid." AND DATE(`zeitpunkt`) >= CURDATE() ORDER BY `zeitpunkt` ASC;";
```

The variable `$tid` could be NULL, but should be interpreted as '0'. Is it possible to do this directly in the mysql-query or should i have a if-clause like this before executing the query?

```
if ($tid == NULL) {
    $tid = 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: warning your code may be susceptible to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or:

```
$sql = "SELECT `eid` FROM `"._ST_EVENT."` WHERE `tid` = ".(!$tid ? 0 : $tid)." AND DATE(`zeitpunkt`) >= CURDATE() ORDER BY `zeitpunkt` ASC;";
```

Answer (score 1):

`COALESCE(id, 0)` in mysql is your friend :)

Read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Comment: if id=null i think will return null not 0 as i have understand

Comment: from doc: Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

Comment: @khaled_webdev why dont you just try `select COALESCE( null, 0 ), COALESCE( 'not null', 0 );` and check the results.

Comment: I tried it, but with no result. The answer from "Tar" is working properly. Strange, because i tried it in another query like this:  COALESCE(selected_team, 0) and "selected_team" is still NULL...

Comment: Well, programming is nice because there are many ways to solve the same problem. If it was Tar whose solution was fitting you the most, make sure you upvote it and mark as an answer :)

Comment: P.S. I was not really sure if I understood what you meant by `COALESCE(selected_team, 0)` being still NULL. It just is impossible :)

Comment: @Torben I am not sure, why `COALESCE` is not working on your end. Alternatively you can try `ifnull` on the column value.

Answer (score 1):

Use this condition:

```
"WHERE `tid` = ".($tid==null?0:$tid)."
```

Comment: i have write it in short time cause buzzy

Answer (score 0):

If you not prefer `ANSI SQL` you can use mysql [`IFNULL(id, 0)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ifnull` in your query.

```
$sql = "SELECT `eid` FROM `"._ST_EVENT."` WHERE `tid` = ifnull(".$tid.",0) AND DATE(`zeitpunkt`) >= CURDATE() ORDER BY `zeitpunkt` ASC;";
```

Comment: @Torben I am not sure, why `COALESCE` is not working on your end. Alternatively you can try `ifnull` on the column value.